# TypeError: searchField.toLowerCase is not a function when using hooks an redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am have been working on a little project to better understand react. I recently converted it to use hooks and I am trying to implement redux, with it. However I get the following error now.

```
TypeError: searchField.toLowerCase is not a function
```

looking at the docs, I stopped using `connect` from `react-redux` and switched to using `useDispatch` and `useSelector`. But I believe I have set up everything correctly but not sure as to why this error being raise.

This is my action.js

```
import { SEARCH_EVENT } from './searchfield_constants';

export const setSearchField = (payload) => ({ type: SEARCH_EVENT, payload });
```

This is my reducer

```
import { SEARCH_EVENT } from './searchfield_constants';

const initialState = {
  searchField: '',
};

export const searchRobots = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_EVENT:
      return { ...state, searchField: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

this is my index.js where I am using the `Provider` from `react-redux`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { searchRobots } from './searchfield/searchfield_reducers';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './App';

const store = createStore(searchRobots);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

finally here is my App.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { setSearchField } from './searchfield/searchfield_actions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import CardList from './components/CardList';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
import Scroll from './components/Scroll';
import Error from './components/Error';
import 'tachyons';
import './styles/App.css';

// const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
//   searchField: state.searchField,
// });

// const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
//   onSearchChange: (e) => dispatch(setSearchField(e.target.value)),
// });

const App = () => {
  const searchField = useSelector(state => state.searchField)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [robots, setRobots] = useState([]);
  // const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      setRobots(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  const filteredRobots = robots.filter((robot) => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
  });

  return !robots.length ? (
    <h1 className='f1 tc'>Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    <div className='App tc'>
      <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={dispatch(setSearchField(e => e.target.value))} />
      <Scroll>
        <Error>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Error>
      </Scroll>
    </div>
  );
};


export default App;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was the following,

I created a function called on searchChange, which calls dispatch and then the setSearchField which uses the e.target.value as the payload.

```
  const onSearchChange = (e) => {
    dispatch(setSearchField(e.target.value));
  };
```

so the final return looks like the following

```
return !robots.length ? (
    <h1 className='f1 tc'>Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    <div className='App tc'>
      <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <Scroll>
        <Error>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Error>
      </Scroll>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In you App.js, convert this line

```
const searchField = useSelector(state => state.searchField)
```

to

```
const { searchField } = useSelector(state => state.searchField)
```

basically de-structure out `searchField` from `state.searchField`

This is attributed to the fact how redux sets state.

In your reducer `searchRobots` the initial state provided by redux will be

```
state = {
...state, 
searchField
}
```

and in this line `return { ...state, searchField: action.payload };`, you're adding
another property `searchField` to `state.searchField` object so you'll need to de-structure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `searchField` value is getting set to undefined or some non-string value.

I found this line to be incorrect

```
<SearchBox searchChange={dispatch(setSearchField(e => e.target.value))} />
```

It should be changed to

```
<SearchBox searchChange={() => dispatch(setSearchField(e => e.target.value))} />
```

So that on search change this function can be called. Currently you are directly calling dispatch and this may be setting your `searchField` to undefined

Also for safer side before using `toLowerCase()` convert it to string ie `searchField.toString().toLowerCase()`